# При использовании $_FILES ошибка с значениями

Tags: php

Не работает функция `move_uploaded_file`, скорее всего проблема в синтаксисе, можете подсказать, почему код так не работает?

```
  $i=0;
if(count($_FILES['filesToUpload'])) {
    foreach ($_FILES['filesToUpload'] as $file) {

    $bla = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['$file[$i]']['tmp_name'], "public/materials/");
    if ($bla) {
        echo "kyaf";
    }
    else {
        echo "noooo";
    }
    echo $file[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

}

Comment: как минимум потому, что `'$file[$i]'` кавычки явно лишние

Comment: Ошибка осталась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```php
$files = $_FILES['filesToUpload'];

if ($files) {
    foreach ($files['tmp_name'] as $k => $fileName) {
        $fileName = $files['name'][$k];  // Определяем имя файла, берем его, которое было при загрузке
        $path = '/public/materials/' . $fileName;  // Загружаем его с полным путем
        if(!move_uploaded_file($fileName, $path))
            echo "Error, while trying to save file<br>";
    }
}
```

`move_uploaded_file(string $filename , string $destination)` принимает второй параметр `$destination`, в котором вы должны указать полный путь для конечного файла, а значит что должны указать `имя.расширение`, к примеру `/public/materials/image.jpg`.

Comment: Да, отпечатался, извиняюсь)

Comment: Загрузив 2 файла, получил 2 еррора)

Comment: Значит смотрите и указывайте верный путь, я не знаю какой вам нужен. Относительный или абсолютный.

Comment: Дело в пути? Обясню вам ситуацию, файл находится в дирекотрии
papka , нужно размещать все в papka/public/materials , ваш код в данном случае должен же работать?

Comment: Прочитал ваш мануал, который вы мне порекомендовали , остался вопрос, который хочу вам задать.
Можно ли этим же способом сохранять в бд сразу несколько картин? 
То есть в таблице где должно была быть одна картинка, сразу 3-5?

Comment: Может ли дело быть в том, что у меня картинка не одна, а это массив?